# I am not able to execute sh after building code using maven

Tags: java, maven, continuous-integration

I am trying a command  mvn clean -DskipTest integration-test which is supposed to build the code, skip unit tests and after building code execute a sh file. But when I execute this command, maven starts building the code and in between it invokes the sh file and once sh is executed, maven continues building code, which is not what I wanted. I want maven should build the code first completely and then execute the sh.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
            <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
              <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
              <groupId>com.vdopia</groupId>
              <artifactId>hudson</artifactId>
              <packaging>pom</packaging>
              <version>1.0.0</version>
              <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
              <properties>
                <gson.version>2.2.4</gson.version>
                <guava.version>18.0</guava.version>
                <junit.version>4.10</junit.version>
                <netty.version>4.0.25.Final</netty.version>
                <wurfl.version>1.5.1</wurfl.version>
                <slf4j.version>1.7.7</slf4j.version>
                <redis.version>2.4.2</redis.version>
                <logger.version>0.3.1</logger.version>
                <org.apache.commons.pool.version>1.6</org.apache.commons.pool.version>
                <execplugin.version>1.3.2</execplugin.version>
                <commons.codec.version>1.9</commons.codec.version>
                <geoip.version>1.2.14</geoip.version>
                <org.json.version>20140107</org.json.version>
                <jacoco.version>0.7.2.201409121644</jacoco.version>
                <spymemcached.version>2.11.5</spymemcached.version>
                <aspectjweaver.version>1.8.0</aspectjweaver.version>
                <aspectjrt.version>1.8.0</aspectjrt.version>
                <apacheasynchttpclient.version>4.1</apacheasynchttpclient.version>
                <shadedjar.version>2.3</shadedjar.version>
            </properties>

              <build>
                  <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                      <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                      <configuration>
                        <source>1.8</source>
                        <target>1.8</target>
                      </configuration>
                    </plugin>

                    <!--plugin>
                       <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                       <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                       <version>${jacoco.version}</version>
                       <executions>
                          <execution>
                             <goals>
                               <goal>prepare-agent</goal></goals>
                          </execution>
                          <execution>
                             <id>report</id>
                             <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                             <goals>
                               <goal>report</goal>
                             </goals>
                          </execution>
                       </executions>
                    </plugin-->
               <!-- To download and link source code in eclipse -->
              <plugin>
                      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                      <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                      <configuration>
                          <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                          <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
                      </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                      <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                      <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                      <version>${execplugin.version}</version>
                  </plugin>
                   <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${shadedjar.version}</version>
                    <executions>
                      <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                          <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                          <transformers>
                            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                              <mainClass>com.vdopia.rtb.netty.Server.HudsonMain</mainClass> </transformer>
            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
              <resource>META-INF/spring.handlers</resource>
            </transformer>
            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
              <resource>META-INF/spring.schemas</resource>
            </transformer>
                          </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                      </execution>
                    </executions>
                  </plugin>

            <!--  REGRESSION TEST -->
                                            <plugin>
                                                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                                                    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
            <executions>
                                                            <execution>
                                                                    <id>Regression_Test</id>
                                                                    <phase>integration-test</phase>
                                                                    <!-- <phase>generate-test-sources</phase> -->
            <configuration>
            <target>

            <exec executable="${basedir}/../../qascripting/Vdopia_Automation/exe/hudson_tc_execute.sh" spawn="false">
            </exec>

            </target>
            </configuration>
                    <goals>
                                                                            <goal>run</goal>
                                                                    </goals>
                                                            </execution>
                                                    </executions>
                                    </plugin>
            <!-- END -->

                  </plugins>
              </build>
              <profiles>
                  <profile>
                      <id>code-coverage</id><build>
                          <plugins>
                              <plugin>
                                  <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                                      <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                                      <version>${jacoco.version}</version>
                                      <executions>
                                          <execution>
                                              <goals>
                                                  <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                                              </goals>
                                          </execution>
                                          <execution>
                                              <id>report</id>
                                              <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                                              <goals>
                                                  <goal>report</goal>
                                              </goals>
                                          </execution>
                                      </executions>
                              </plugin>
                          </plugins>
                      </build>
                  </profile>
              </profiles> <modules>
                <module>utils</module>
                <module>rtb</module>
                <module>adResponse</module>
                <module>DAL</module>
                <module>cache</module>
                <module>redis</module>
                <module>extRequestProcessor</module>
                <module>netty</module>
                <module>ResponseGenerator</module>
                <module>RequestHandler</module>
                <module>Filter</module>
                <module>fluentData</module>
                <module>vast</module>
                <module>externalcache</module>
                <module>templates</module>
                <module>statistics</module>
              </modules>

              <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                  <groupId>junit</groupId>
                  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                  <version>${junit.version}</version>
                  <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>

               <dependency>
                  <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
                  <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
                  <version>${gson.version}</version>
                  <type>jar</type>
                </dependency>

              <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                    <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
              </dependency>
              <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                    <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
              </dependency>
              </dependencies>
            </project>
```

Comment: This question is not off the topic...

Comment: What I find odd, is that you command Maven to skip the Integration phase, but you bind your shell script execution to this same phase. 
Also, I'm not sure what you mean with "building the code". Did you mean compiling? Or what phase would you like to have happened before you execute the shell script? 

Did you check the Apache Guide to the Maven Lifecycle? (https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html)

Comment: @Rob: Well my scenario is:  I am using the above pom.xml in jenkins which  compile and build the developer code. Now I want to trigger my automated test by a hudson_tc_execute.sh file which is configured in the above pom.xml with id = Regression_Test, this sh file calls an ANT script to compile Regression_Test code and execute the Regression_Test. Now my problem is: if I use  command mvn clean integration-test then developer doesn't get complied fully and in between the sh file is invoked rather I want sh to invoked after compilation of developer code. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Ok I understand that. Why do you use an Ant script to compile the regression test and execute it? You can also compile and execute it all from within Maven, and you'll not have to deal with interoperability. You can use the `build-helper-maven-plugin` to add test sources, which will create a test-jar with compiled test code. You can execute your tests in the destined phase. 

I'd try to stay as close to the Maven way of working as possible, because there is a lot already out there. The more you deviate from it, the more weird problems you'll encounter.

Comment: @Rob: I am not sure how do I use maven to build automation code and use that behaviour in existing pom, I've been executing automation code independently using ANT. I found easier to integrate existing ANT script in existing pom.xml, Now I can trigger the automation code with pom but the only problem is: maven invokes the executable in between building the developer code.